# USB stick not usable

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, controller

Someone asked me to check on his usb stick because it was not recognized properly and he wanted to get his data back. It's a PHILIPS FM16FD70B.
Windows disk manager reports `No Media` but i can mount it with a letter. When I try to chkdsk, it just says `unable to open the volume in direct access`.
In linux, neither fdisk or parted see it. It does appear (only the disk, not the partitions) in /dev but when I try to copy from it using dd it just says `'/dev/sdc': No medium found`.
When I look at dmesg, i have this :

```
[May 8 11:25] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.140243] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201, bcdDevice= 0.00
[  +0.000007] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.002358] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0.002429] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[  +0.059393] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  +0.775138] audit: type=1101 audit(1588929907.791:92): pid=1247 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_time acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostn>
[  +0.000175] audit: type=1110 audit(1588929907.791:93): pid=1247 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_env acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? a>
[  +0.001889] audit: type=1105 audit(1588929907.794:94): pid=1247 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" host>
[  +0.178887] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     NAND     USB2DISK         0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  +0.040526] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Also, I'm not sure it's useful but the stick was mainly used with MacOS.
I'm thinking about a dead controller (especially with the idVendor=ffff), but since the key is only 6 months old, I'm not quite sure. Do you have any idea if the data is recoverable or if I can do anything about it ?

Comment: You already tried Windows, Linux and even direct block access to the raw device. There are not much options left - may be trying to access the flash chip directly?

Comment: Do you know how can I do that? Thanks for your answer

Comment: That requires a lot of experience and suitable equipment. As long as you aren't an electronic nerd this is beyond your skills. Additionally the data in the flash memory may be scattered because of the wear-leveling algorithm applied by the controller. If the data is worth ~200 USD or more you may try it in a professional data recovery center.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were talking about another way using a special software or something. I think I'll just drop it. Thanks for your help!